# Change IP in all DNS zones on Microsoft Windows DNS Server

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows-dns

We host about 125 DNS forward-lookup zones on a Microsoft Windows Server 2003 DNS Server. We need to migrate to a new block of IPs and don't want to go through each zone manually. What's the best way to globally change one ip (1.1.1.1, for example) to another (2.2.2.2, for example) in ALL DNS zones and records?

Answer (score 4):

You could script the necessary actions by either using the [DNSCMD utility](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc778513%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) or the [DNS WMI provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682868%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). If both ways are not an option for some reason, you might consider changing your RRs through dynamic DNS updates - for example using [`nsupdate`](http://caunter.ca/nsupdate.txt) from the ISC BIND package. You might have to relax ACLs on your zones and RRs for this to work.